# Statuscode: 404 on live server, 200 on localhost

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having a weird bug.. My app works fine, the only weird thing is that I get a 404 error message in my network console whenever I'm not on the Homepage (my content still loads and my app works perfectly but I just get this message). because of this, when I for example put my link in a powerpoint and someone clicks on it, it will not work.

I don't have this error on my localhost.

**Live server**

[image: on live server]

**Localhost**

[image: on localhost]

I'm using `react-router-dom` for handling my routes.
here is my code:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
```

```
const App = () => {

    const search_slug_options = [
        `/${search}/${page}=:page?/:id?`,
        `/${search}/:value_1?/:value_2?/${page}=:page?/:id?`,
        `/${search}/:value_1?/${page}=:page?/:id?`,
        `/${search}/:value_2?/${page}=:page?/:id?`,

        `/${search}/:value_1?/:value_2?/:id?`,
        `/${search}/:value_1?/:id?`,
        `/${search}/:value_2?/:id?`
    ]


    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/:keyboard?" render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />
                {search_slug_options.map((path, index) => <Route key={index} path={path} render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />)}
                <Route path="/user/:id/:name/:mod?" render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />
                <Route path="/user/:id/:name?" render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />
                <Route exact path="/privacy/policy" render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />
                <Route path="/:id?/:value?" render={(props) => <SomeComponent {...props} />} />
                <Route path="*" render={(props) => <NotFound {...props} />} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I really have no idea, can anyone help?

**EDIT :**

So, I'm using AWS amplify and I have tried @vishnu Singh his answer. It gave me a blank page, I changed it back to the settings that it had before (404 rewrite).

Now whenever I soft refresh my page, only my HTML file loads in.

When I hard refresh the page, HTML, CSS and JS file loads in and webApp works perfectly

Also weirdly enough, I have 2 domains linked to this webApp, only one of them has this problem

Comment: Can you share more details about your server, like which server are you using `nginx`, `express` server on `node.js` or anything else?
For localhost you might be using a development server which handles all routes and points it to your `index.html`

Comment: My app is deployed on an AWS amplify server

Comment: I haven't used `aws amplify`. This documentation might help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html choose -  `source uri`: `/<*>`, `redirect uri`: `/index.html` and the `type` should be `200`.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `nginx` then add following configuration to your server config file.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

What it really does is any route starting with a `/` will send the `index.html` file. So basically any route like `/user` or `/user/1/john-doe`, all of them will be getting same `index.html` file from `nginx` server.

After getting the `index.html` file in the browser, `react-router` will parse the url and load corresponding component as you declared in your react application.

Same functionality can be achieved with an `express.js` server by following snippet:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

// assuming your source code is in '<project root>/public' directory
app.use('/', express.static('public'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server started"))
```

for more details you can check [express.js official documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Edit:

As you are using `aws-amplify`. Following solution might work:

1. Login to aws console.
2. Go to AWS Amplify service.
3. Choose **Rewrites and redirects** settings in the left navigation pane.
4. Then click on **Add rule**.
5. Set Source URI as: `/<*>`
6. Set Target URI as: `/index.html` (assuming `index.html` is placed in root)
7. Set Type as: `200 (Rewrite)`
8. Click on **Save**.

[image]

Image credits: AWS amplify [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html).

Comment: I did this for AWS amplify, I got a blank page. so I changed it back to what it was (404 rewrite), and now it seems that whenever I refresh the page, only my HTML loads in, not my js and css files.

Comment: Weirdly enough, when I hard refresh (ctrl + f5) the page, it loads perfectly again. but normal refresh makes my Js and css files not load in

Comment: Okay... there are two possibility, either its a cache problem or your public static files are not being served after this configuration. Cache problem can be solved if you set type to 301 (Redirect Permanent), for later problem you may need another routing rule in your configuration for static files and reorder it before last route. You can take help from above mentioned AWS amplify redirect page.